# How can I stop food mixture from dissociating in water?

Tags: diet, turtles, hygiene

I've been trying a new way of feeding my turtle by mixing a variety of vegetables with chicken and/or prawns. I do so by mincing everything then combining them and crushing them together. I then form them into balls.

The problem is that they dissociate once placed in water. I know dehydration might be a solution but I do not have a dehydrator and I think placing them in the sun will get unwanted organisms eating them and probably contaminating them.

Are there any other ways to prevent dissociation? And if no then what is the best way of dehydration that minimises nutrient loss and avoids contamination?

Answer (score 3):

A way to keep the food together is to turn it into gelatin.

From this site: http://aquariadise.com/gel-fish-food/

1. Find or make a recipe that contains the food you want to give your
   turtle, and collect the ingredients you need.
2. Toss it in the blender.
3. Add gelatin so the food won't fall apart.
4. Pour the resulting mixture in ziplock bags and flatten them so you
   can break off pieces easily or into ice-cube trays.
5. Give a bit to see if your turtle likes or not.

NOTE: Gel food can be kept in the freezer for long periods of time – just thaw before feeding and you’re ready to go!